# How to read from stdin Linux and set it as input in python

Tags: python, linux, bash

This is a sample code:

```
var1 = float(input('Enter time interval: '))
print(f'OK, time interval is {var1}')
# doing something with above variable
```

I want to run this `python` file like this without changing the code if possible:

```
python file.py 0<'15'
```

But I get this error:

```
-bash: 15: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the input through a pipe:

```
echo 15 | python file.py
```

Or, with lesser known syntax, using process substitution, which I'm mentioning because it seems like this is what you were trying to do:

```
python file.py < <(echo 15)
```

In both cases, be aware of the shell's quoting rules and add quotes accordingly.

If there are multiple lines, a bash heredoc might be easier:

```
python file.py <<EOF
line1
line2
line3
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a

```
python file.py <<<15
```

The `<<<` redirection takes the string to its right and feeds it to the program as standard input.